# Simple shell script, too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting a `line 1: [: too many arguments` error when I execute this script:

```
if [ $(/amtu/Utilities/amtu_daemon status) = 'The daemon is stopped.' ];
    then
        echo "matched"
    else
        echo "no matched"
fi
```

I'm really new to shell and everything on google about too many arguments is way too specific to the individual issue. Can anyone let me know what is wrong with my script?

Comment: enclose `$(...)` in quotation marks. Otherwise, a space in the output breaks your syntax.

Comment: Stackoverflow will give you answers within minutes, but you can also diagnose several common bash issues, including this one, in real time with [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.com).

Comment: I think you meant [ShellCheck.net](http://shellcheck.net), not .com :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command `/amtu/Utilities/amtu_daemon status` likely has multiple words. Quoting it should solve it.

Change:

```
if [ $(/amtu/Utilities/amtu_daemon status) = 'The daemon is stopped.' ];
```

to:

```
if [ "$(/amtu/Utilities/amtu_daemon status)" = 'The daemon is stopped.' ];
```

Comment: Yes! That worked. Thanks so much. I can accept your answer in 11 minutes.